# Auto calculate fields in hibernate entity

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have simple entity class for organization:

```
@javax.persistence.Entity
@javax.persistence.Table(name = "organization", catalog = "public")
public class Organization implements Serializable {
    public Organization() {
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "code")
    private String code;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="parentunit", updatable = false, insertable = false)
    private Organization parentUnitEntity;

    @Column(name = "unitpath")
    private String unitPath;

    // getters, setters, other fields and so on
}
```

When I add new Organization and persist it, I want to set automatically field `unitPath` with formula: `parentUnitEntity.unitPath + '/' + code`.

How to do it properly? I tried `@Formula` - but it not working for insert. I don't want to do it by hands, because I want write code that don't know anything about entity, only persist it (data for objects come from another system).

Answer (score 0):

`@Formula` is used only when retrieving the entity from database, so it won't help you.

One solution might be to use `@org.hibernate.annotations.SQLUpdate` and `@org.hibernate.annotations.SQLInsert`. With those annotations, you can override the insert/update statements hibernate executes. The problem is, you also want to use a detail table (self-referencing table) in your update and these annotations are not flexible enough to achieve this.

Another solution is to write a custom `UserType` to handle the conversion. You would implement interfaces such as `CompositeUserType` and `DynamicParameterizedType`. This solution is more flexible but it is not a trivial task. You can check out sources on the internet or have a look at the book *JPA Persistence with Hibernate* to get the idea.

Third solution I would propose is to use an instead-of update trigger in the database. This solution does not involve JPA, you should create the trigger in the database. Check out http://www.rebellionrider.com/how-to-create-instead-of-update-trigger-in-oracle-pl-sql/ for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use an entity listener:

```
public class Organization implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "code")
    private String code;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="parentunit", updatable = false, insertable = false)
    private Organization parentUnitEntity;

    @Column(name = "unitpath")
    private String unitPath;

    @PrePersist
    protected void setUnitPath(){
       if(parentUnitEntity != null){
           unitPath = parentUnitEntity.getUnitPath() + "/" + code;
       }
    }
}
```